# Combobox has an extra member

Tags: c#, datetime-format, globalization

So I'm using MetroCombobox and I'm trying populate it with abbreviated month names but I'm getting an extra member at the bottom of the list.

This is my code:

```
var months = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
mcbxGreenCardMonth.DataSource = months;
```

I don't understand why is it generating an extra member! Can someone tell me why and how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the 13th element of the array is an empty string.Try this,

```
var months = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
comboBox1.DataSource = months.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: yap, that fixed the problem and I'll mark it as answer as soon as it allows me. But why this happens??? the 13th element?

Comment: there is an empty string, thats why you see , upvote if possible

Comment: I have upvoted it. ill mark it soon as well. Thanks anyways.